# Python: Appending string constructed out of multiple lines to list

Tags: python, string, list, parsing, append

I'm trying to parse a txt file and put sentences in a list that fit my criteria.
The text file consists of several thousand lines and I'm looking for lines that start with a specific string, lets call this string 'start'. 
The lines in this text file can belong together and are somehow seperated with `\n` at random.

This means I have to look for any string that starts with 'start', put it in an empty string 'complete' and then continue scanning each line after that to see if it also starts with 'start'.

If not then I need to append it to 'complete' because then it is part of the entire sentence. If it does I need to append 'complete' to a list, create a new, empty 'complete' string and start appending to that one. This way I can loop through the entire text file without paying attention to the number of lines a sentence exists of.

My code thusfar:

```
import sys, string
lines_1=[]
startswith = ('keys', 'values', 'files', 'folders', 'total')
completeline = ''

with open (sys.argv[1]) as f:
    data = f.read()
for line in data:
    if line.lower().startswith(startswith):
        completeline = line
    else:
        completeline += line

lines_1.append(completeline)

# check some stuff in output
for l in lines_1:
    print "______"
    print l
print len(lines_1)
```

However this puts the entire content in 1 item in the list, where I'd like everything to be seperated.

Keep in mind that the lines composing one sentence can span one, two, 10 or 1000 lines so it needs to spot the next `startswith` value, append the existing `completeline` to the list and then fill `completeline` up with the next sentence.

Much obliged!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues:

1. Iterating over a string, not lines:

When you iterate over a string, the value yielded is a character, not a line. This means `for line in data:` is going character by character through the string. Split your input by newlines, returning a list, which you then iterate over. e.g. `for line in data.split('\n'):`

2. Overwriting the completeline inside the loop

You append a completed line at the end of the loop, but not when you start recording a new line inside the loop. Change the `if` in the loop to something like this:

```
if line.lower().startswith(startswith):
    if completeline:
        lines_1.append(completeline)
    completeline = line
```

Comment: I see, I didn't know iterating over a string yields characters. I've tested it and it's true indeed. Thanks for that.
I don't quite get what you mean with add 'if completeline'. How does it know that that value is true or false?

Comment: On the first iteration, completeline will be empty, and you don't want to add an empty string to lines_1 array. A blank string is falsy, so the `if` will fail.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

For task like this

"I'm trying to parse a txt file and put sentences in a list that fit my criteria"

I usually prefer using dictionary for such kind of ideas, for example

```
from collections import defaultdict
seperatedItems = defaultdict(list)

for sentence in fileDataAsAList:
     if satisfiesCriteria("start",sentence):
          seperatedItems["start"].append(sentence)

def satisfiesCriteria(criteria,sentence):
     if sentence.lower.startswith(criteria):
         return True

     return False
```

Something like this should suffise.. the code is just for giving you idea of what you might like to do.. you can have list of criterias and loop over them which will add sentences related to different creterias into dictionary something like this

mycriterias = ['start','begin','whatever']

```
for criteria in mycriterias:
    for sentence in fileDataAsAList:
       if satisfiesCriteria(criteria ,sentence):
           seperatedItems[criteria ].append(sentence)
```

mind the spellings :p

Comment: This looks promising! I'll look into it and get back to this